# How to disable @Scheduled while building a Spring-boot project

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I'm working on a Spring-Boot project with Job Scheduling inside the project. I have job schedule class like this,

```
@Component
public class JobScheduleService {
  
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 300000)
    public void excutePaymentJob(){
        // Do Something
    }

}
```

While I'm building a project through **"mvn clean install"** command. The "excutePaymentJob()" function will be executed on a building process.

Is there anyway to disable this on a building phase ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: No... You might use a startup delay etc.

Comment: If it's during testing or similar you might make the task component conditional.

Comment: @Hikaru Shindo please share with us the class that has `@EnableScheduling` and also the test that loads this configuration

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos There's no 'EnableScheduling' in the project. There're only 'Scheduled(fixedRate = 300000)' in a class.

Comment: @HikaruShindo Did you find a solution? I am solving the exact same problem.