# How do not start application while running mvn package?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am using such `@Service` class to run services after application boot.

```
@Service
@Conditional(LoadOnProductionEnvironment.class)
public class RunnerProduction {

    static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RunnerProduction.class);

    private final FooBarService runner;

    public RunnerProduction(FooBarService runner) {
        this.runner = AssertUtils.notNull(runner, "runner");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void run() {
        runner.run();
    }

}
```

When I creating standalone executable `jar` package `mvn clean package -Pproduction`, application is started and immediately crashes because setting for `production` profile is not visible on development environment.

Is it possible to create package but do not start the application itself? Possibly I can change how the services start but i would like to keep the manual start.

Edit: One more problem with this setup - if I have some methods annotated with `@Scheduled` then `mvn clean package` starts the application and it waits, the Maven build is not completed.

Edit 2: When I use `@Scheduled` application start and stay alive during `mvn clean package`.

```
  @Scheduled(timeUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES, fixedDelay = 15)
public void scheduled() {
runner.run();
    }
}
```

Edit 3: Related question: [How to disable @Scheduled while building a Spring-boot project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72291530/1315357) - without resolution.

Edit 4: Console log when `@Scheduled(timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS, fixedDelay = 5, initialDelay = 1)` is active. (I let run 5 scheduled executions and cancel application with cmd+c at the end).

```
jnemec@jirka-macbook manitutrader-dataprocessor % mvn clean package -Pproduction -DskipTests
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------< com.manitutrader:manitutrader-dataprocessor >-------------
[INFO] Building manitutrader-dataprocessor 1.0
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/jnemec/IdeaProjects/manitutrader/manitutrader-dataprocessor/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot:3.0.0:run (default) > test-compile @ manitutrader-dataprocessor >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 18 source files to /Users/jnemec/IdeaProjects/manitutrader/manitutrader-dataprocessor/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/jnemec/IdeaProjects/manitutrader/manitutrader-dataprocessor/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot:3.0.0:run (default) < test-compile @ manitutrader-dataprocessor <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot:3.0.0:run (default) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.7.12)

2023-06-14 08:38:22.976  INFO 76330 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.d.ApplicationRoot                    : Starting ApplicationRoot using Java 17.0.6 on jirka-macbook.local with PID 76330 (/Users/jnemec/IdeaProjects/manitutrader/manitutrader-dataprocessor/target/classes started by jnemec in /Users/jnemec/IdeaProjects/manitutrader/manitutrader-dataprocessor)
2023-06-14 08:38:22.977 DEBUG 76330 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.d.ApplicationRoot                    : Running with Spring Boot v2.7.12, Spring v5.3.27
2023-06-14 08:38:22.977  INFO 76330 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.d.ApplicationRoot                    : The following 1 profile is active: "production"
2023-06-14 08:38:22.993  INFO 76330 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-06-14 08:38:23.119  INFO 76330 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-06-14 08:38:23.144  INFO 76330 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 22 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-06-14 08:38:23.232  INFO 76330 --- [  restartedMain] ptablePropertiesBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Post-processing PropertySource instances
2023-06-14 08:38:23.233  INFO 76330 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Skipping PropertySource configurationProperties [class org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertySource
2023-06-14 08:38:23.233  INFO 76330 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource systemProperties [org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2023-06-14 08:38:23.233  INFO 76330 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource systemEnvironment [org.springframework.boot.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySourceEnvironmentPostProcessor$OriginAwareSystemEnvironmentPropertySource] to EncryptableSystemEnvironmentPropertySourceWrapper
2023-06-14 08:38:23.234  INFO 76330 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource random [org.springframework.boot.env.RandomValuePropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
2023-06-14 08:38:23.234  INFO 76330 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource Config resource 'class path resource [application-production.properties]' via location 'optional:classpath:/' [org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedMapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2023-06-14 08:38:23.234  INFO 76330 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource Config resource 'class path resource [application.properties]' via location 'optional:classpath:/' [org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedMapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2023-06-14 08:38:23.234  INFO 76330 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource devtools [org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2023-06-14 08:38:23.234  INFO 76330 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource class path resource [application.properties] [org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2023-06-14 08:38:23.234  INFO 76330 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource URL [file:/Users/jnemec/.app/credentials.properties] [org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2023-06-14 08:38:23.266  INFO 76330 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.f.DefaultLazyPropertyFilter        : Property Filter custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyFilter'. Initializing Default Property Filter
2023-06-14 08:38:23.270  INFO 76330 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.r.DefaultLazyPropertyResolver      : Property Resolver custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyResolver'. Initializing Default Property Resolver
2023-06-14 08:38:23.271  INFO 76330 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.d.DefaultLazyPropertyDetector      : Property Detector custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyDetector'. Initializing Default Property Detector
2023-06-14 08:38:23.282  INFO 76330 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.e.DefaultLazyEncryptor             : Found Custom Encryptor Bean org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.PooledPBEStringEncryptor@7a5575a0 with name: jasyptStringEncryptor
2023-06-14 08:38:23.582  INFO 76330 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-06-14 08:38:23.741  INFO 76330 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.d.ApplicationRoot                    : Started ApplicationRoot in 0.889 seconds (JVM running for 1.098)
2023-06-14 08:38:24.744  INFO 76330 --- [   scheduling-1] c.m.d.r.RunnerProduction                 : ------------------------- @Scheduled executed: 2023-06-14T08:38:24.741572
2023-06-14 08:38:29.751  INFO 76330 --- [   scheduling-1] c.m.d.r.RunnerProduction                 : ------------------------- @Scheduled executed: 2023-06-14T08:38:29.751377
2023-06-14 08:38:34.757  INFO 76330 --- [   scheduling-1] c.m.d.r.RunnerProduction                 : ------------------------- @Scheduled executed: 2023-06-14T08:38:34.757749
2023-06-14 08:38:39.764  INFO 76330 --- [   scheduling-1] c.m.d.r.RunnerProduction                 : ------------------------- @Scheduled executed: 2023-06-14T08:38:39.764081
2023-06-14 08:38:44.768  INFO 76330 --- [   scheduling-1] c.m.d.r.RunnerProduction                 : ------------------------- @Scheduled executed: 2023-06-14T08:38:44.768008
^C2023-06-14 08:38:45.877  INFO 76330 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 18 source files to /Users/jnemec/IdeaProjects/manitutrader/manitutrader-dataprocessor/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/jnemec/IdeaProjects/manitutrader/manitutrader-dataprocessor/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- surefire:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jar:3.2.2:jar (default-jar) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/jnemec/IdeaProjects/manitutrader/manitutrader-dataprocessor/target/manitutrader-dataprocessor.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot:3.0.0:repackage (repackage) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Layout: JAR
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot:3.0.0:repackage (default) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Layout: JAR
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  24.689 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-06-14T08:38:46+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Edit 5: Console log with `@PostConstruct` method - now I do not have any service to executed int this method, but if I would, it will be executed.

```
jnemec@jirka-macbook manitutrader-dataprocessor % mvn clean package -Pproduction -DskipTests
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------< com.manitutrader:manitutrader-dataprocessor >-------------
[INFO] Building manitutrader-dataprocessor 1.0
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/jnemec/IdeaProjects/manitutrader/manitutrader-dataprocessor/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot:3.0.0:run (default) > test-compile @ manitutrader-dataprocessor >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 18 source files to /Users/jnemec/IdeaProjects/manitutrader/manitutrader-dataprocessor/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/jnemec/IdeaProjects/manitutrader/manitutrader-dataprocessor/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot:3.0.0:run (default) < test-compile @ manitutrader-dataprocessor <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot:3.0.0:run (default) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.7.12)

2023-06-14 08:42:02.796  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.d.ApplicationRoot                    : Starting ApplicationRoot using Java 17.0.6 on jirka-macbook.local with PID 76786 (/Users/jnemec/IdeaProjects/manitutrader/manitutrader-dataprocessor/target/classes started by jnemec in /Users/jnemec/IdeaProjects/manitutrader/manitutrader-dataprocessor)
2023-06-14 08:42:02.798 DEBUG 76786 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.d.ApplicationRoot                    : Running with Spring Boot v2.7.12, Spring v5.3.27
2023-06-14 08:42:02.798  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.d.ApplicationRoot                    : The following 1 profile is active: "production"
2023-06-14 08:42:02.813  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-06-14 08:42:02.941  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-06-14 08:42:02.986  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 43 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-06-14 08:42:03.075  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] ptablePropertiesBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Post-processing PropertySource instances
2023-06-14 08:42:03.076  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Skipping PropertySource configurationProperties [class org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertySource
2023-06-14 08:42:03.076  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource systemProperties [org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2023-06-14 08:42:03.076  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource systemEnvironment [org.springframework.boot.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySourceEnvironmentPostProcessor$OriginAwareSystemEnvironmentPropertySource] to EncryptableSystemEnvironmentPropertySourceWrapper
2023-06-14 08:42:03.076  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource random [org.springframework.boot.env.RandomValuePropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
2023-06-14 08:42:03.076  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource Config resource 'class path resource [application-production.properties]' via location 'optional:classpath:/' [org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedMapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2023-06-14 08:42:03.076  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource Config resource 'class path resource [application.properties]' via location 'optional:classpath:/' [org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedMapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2023-06-14 08:42:03.076  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource devtools [org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2023-06-14 08:42:03.077  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource class path resource [application.properties] [org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2023-06-14 08:42:03.077  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource URL [file:/Users/jnemec/.app/credentials.properties] [org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2023-06-14 08:42:03.107  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.f.DefaultLazyPropertyFilter        : Property Filter custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyFilter'. Initializing Default Property Filter
2023-06-14 08:42:03.111  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.r.DefaultLazyPropertyResolver      : Property Resolver custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyResolver'. Initializing Default Property Resolver
2023-06-14 08:42:03.112  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.d.DefaultLazyPropertyDetector      : Property Detector custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyDetector'. Initializing Default Property Detector
2023-06-14 08:42:03.123  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.e.DefaultLazyEncryptor             : Found Custom Encryptor Bean org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.PooledPBEStringEncryptor@5d35edbc with name: jasyptStringEncryptor
2023-06-14 08:42:03.429  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-06-14 08:42:03.466  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.d.r.RunnerProduction                 : ------------------------- @PostConstruct executed
2023-06-14 08:42:03.590  INFO 76786 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.d.ApplicationRoot                    : Started ApplicationRoot in 0.92 seconds (JVM running for 1.141)
2023-06-14 08:42:03.593  INFO 76786 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 18 source files to /Users/jnemec/IdeaProjects/manitutrader/manitutrader-dataprocessor/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/jnemec/IdeaProjects/manitutrader/manitutrader-dataprocessor/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- surefire:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jar:3.2.2:jar (default-jar) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/jnemec/IdeaProjects/manitutrader/manitutrader-dataprocessor/target/manitutrader-dataprocessor.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot:3.0.0:repackage (repackage) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Layout: JAR
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot:3.0.0:repackage (default) @ manitutrader-dataprocessor ---
[INFO] Layout: JAR
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.724 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-06-14T08:42:04+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, there is a test class annotated with `@SpringBootTest`, in the `src.test.java...` package, to verify the loading of the application context. That test, and other tests if exist, is run during the Maven test phase.

You can delete the default test class (if there are no other test classes) or skip the tests using the following command:

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

---

Edit:

After OP provided the console output, it appears the execution for the `run` goal was defined in the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` which was causing the running of the application during `test-compile` Maven phase. Removing it fixes the issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, but maybe I don't understand the answer, I didn't solve the tests at all, but the fact that the application starts during packaging. Did I miss something?

Comment: The application starts during packaging because tests are being run. If you use the mentioned command, tests would be skipped, thus application wouldn't be started.

Comment: Thank you for the effort but it's definitely not working as you mention, I've tested it. Even if I turn off the tests (which I don't want to turn off), the application is started and `@PostConstruct` method is executed. If I use another method using the `@Scheduled` annotation, not only is the application started, but even if the `initialDelay` parameter is used, the application waits for this amount of time. Is there really no way to fix this? (I don't have any test classes yet).

Comment: Can you provide the output from the console after you run  `mvn clean package`? To see whats really happening.

Comment: I added a console log for both variants of execution.

Comment: Okay, now it's more clear. The last thing I'm asking for is the part of the `pom.xml` where `spring-boot-maven-plugin` plugin is defined, there is probably the cause of the issue.

Comment: You are right, mistake on my side - in `spring-boot-maven-plugin` I had `run` goal and not `repackage` goal. It was left over after testing one thing, after removing it now works as expected. Thanks for the solution!